# simple flask application form, form page not functioning

Tags: python, forms, flask

form page not displaying response,

I left off some tags that were supposed to be closed. I changed that already. Basically, once i fill out the form and click on the submit button it should take me to the display page where it displays a string such as " Hello" + string + "thank you for submitting!"

main.py code

```
#import the flask module 
from flask import Flask, render_template, request,url_for

ap Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')


@app.route("/teams")
def teams():
    return render_template('teams.html') 

@app.route("/form", methods = ['GET','POST'])
def form():
    #get the method of the post and the method of the get 
    if request.method == "POST"  and request.form.get('submit'):
        string = request.form.get('name')
        feedback = "Hello" + string + "\n Thank you for submiting!!"
//
    else:
        return render_template('form.html').format(feedback = "")
```

Comment: What do you want to check in the `if ` clause with the `request.form.get('submit')` part? This will be false and thats why the form is loaded again.

Comment: If the ‘submit’ button is pressed then it will return feedback

Answer (score 0):

If everything is ok with you except that feedback is not displaying then do this:

```
def form():
#get the method of the post and the method of the get 
    if request.method == "POST"  and request.form.get('submit'):
        string = request.form.get('name')
        feedback = "Hello" + string + "\n Thank you for submiting!!"
        return render_template('display.html', feedback=feedback)
    else:
        feedback = ... # define feedback here
        return render_template('form.html', feedback=feedback)
```

Comment: I’m getting internal server error when i changed that

Comment: On the terminal , the error is  unboundlocalerror : local variable ‘feedback’ referenced before assignment

Comment: in the else section of the if then else block, feedback is not defined. I will edit the answer

Comment: the problem here is that the `if` block is never true. Because in the form there is nothing with the name `submit`. Hitting the Submit Button does not add this to the Form Data.

Comment: Then  don't send the feedback in the else block or set it to none

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the Comments with the Code you provide the `if` Block never gets true. Because inside the Form Data there is no thing called `submit`.
To solve this your form should look like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE  html>
<html>
<head> 
    <title>World Cup</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> What team are you going to support? </h1>
    <h2> Please fill in the information in the bottom</h2>
    <br> <br>

    <nav> <a href = "{{url_for('home')}}">Home</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 
    <a href = "{{url_for('teams')}}">Teams</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 
    <a href = "{{url_for('form')}}">Form</a>  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 
    </nav>
    <br> <br>
    <form method = "post">
        <label> Name:
        <input type ="text" name = "name"></label>
        <br> <br>

        <label> Comments:
        <input type = "text" name = "Comments"> </label>
        <br> <br>

        <input type = "submit" name="submit" value = "Submit">
        <input type = "reset">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

So i added the `name` Attribute to the `Submit` Button. I also changed the `name` Attribute of the Comment button because it is identically with the name of the `Name` Field.

The second Problem is the call of `render_template`. To pass Variables to the Form you have to put them into the `render_template` call.

This is how your `route` should look like:

```py
@app.route("/form", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def form():
    # get the method of the post and the method of the get
    if request.method == "POST" and request.form.get("submit"):
        string = request.form.get("name")
        feedback = "Hello" + string + "\n Thank you for submiting!!"
        return render_template("display.html", feedback=feedback)
    else:
        return render_template("form.html")
```